# Why does my mouse cursor change to a plus sign in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I just see strange behaviour in Eclipse . I am developing one android project . In one activity my cursor change to plus sign except this it works fine .

Can you tell me how to solve this ?

how to change to arrow sign in that particular activity ?

Comment: Try this one. Window -> Close All Perspectives. And, rebuild the perspective using Window -> Open perspective -> Java(Default) -> Ok.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You might have selected the tool, `Toggle Block Selection Mode <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> so that's why your mouse point is converted to + sign, Toggle it off and it will be simple again.

More to read about this Mode: [Click Here](http://tkilla.ch/column_mode/)

Answer (score 7):

Simply do the below steps -

1. Window -> Close All Perspectives. And, rebuild your perspective.
2. Window -> Open perspective -> Java(Default) -> Ok.

Hope these 2 steps may helpful to you.

Comment: +1 Hmm..nice to use the perspective..but what about if i want to use the current perspectives only :)

Comment: @MKJParekh , Because of that i accept your answer . Because it works with current perspective.

Comment: This particular issue drove me crazy. Just wanted to let you know that you made my day with this suggestion! Cheers!